# Parallel deployment of Azure AppService using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-appservice

I am trying to solve a use-case of deploying 20 to 30 Azure AppServices using ARM template based on Admin decision.

This is happening through c# webapi using Microsoft Fluent library(Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent & Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent),

```
var creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(clientId, 
                                                               clientSecret, 
                                                               tenantId, 
                                                               AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure.Authenticate(creds).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
var deployment = azure.Deployments.Define($"deployment-{userName}")
                                  .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                                  .WithTemplate(templateJson.ToString())
                                  .WithParametersLink(templateParamsBlobURL, "1.0.0.0")
                                  .WithMode(Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Models.DeploymentMode.Incremental)
                                  .Create();
```

**Problem statement**
When the admin decides to run 20 AppServices, then the above lines of code will execute and provision these AppServices, the decision is based on admin.

For me the Deployment is happening in sequential manner i.e., upon completing one AppService deployment then it triggers the next AppService deployment, which takes huge time to complete the entire operation. I am trying to achieve the deployment of 20 AppServices(decided by admin) in parallel so that the provisioning completes at the earliest

Kindly assist me on **how to achieve the parallel deployment of AppServices using ARM template**

Comment: Aren't you using Loop?

Comment: Could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources) for iteration the resources. Let us know if it helps

Comment: thanks @AjayKumarGhose-MT, this document helped me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for confirming @*Guptha*, posted the same as an answer to help other community members for the similar query , To iteration multiple resources at a time in ARM TEMPLATE .

> Use your Azure Resource Manager template to create multiple instances
> of a resource (ARM template). You can dynamically set the quantity of
> resources to deploy by adding a copy loop to the resources section of
> your template.

For example to create multiple storage accounts ;

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageCount": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 3
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(copyIndex(),'storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {},
      "copy": {
        "name": "storagecopy",
        "count": "[parameters('storageCount')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For complete setup please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Resource iteration in ARM templates***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources)